# IBM API Connect health check

Tags: apiconnect, apiconnect-test-monitor

Would like to know in API Connect, is there a built-in way to check health of an API in Prod? (Like Springboot actuator/health)

If not, best way recommended to implement health check for each of our APIs that we are about to develop in API Connect

Regards,
Martand

Answer (score 0):

API Connect v2018 portals do not have an inbuilt health check, they removed it in v5. There is a RFE to request this functionality.

For the gateway component the best way is to use a tcp_half_open health check on the IP/Port that your gateway is listening on. Note it has to be tcp_half_open otherwise your appliance will be spammed with TLS handshake errors.

This will confirm that the gateway is up and running and serving requests. You should also check the management port is running, as your gateway might not be synchronizing with the APIM and it's possible that it is serving up an old API.

Health checks on an individual API are a little more difficult, and would need to be added as a separate operation in your spec.

Comment: Thank you @Brendon S. Currently trying to implement APIs individually with GET method and proxying backend Health check endpoints.